# Load URL into a div

Tags: javascript

this script load content using an IFRAME is there any way to just load the content from the page but not as iframe?

something like

```
$("#content2").load($(this).attr("page"));
```

But i can't seem to make it work on the above script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadURL(u) { 
document.getElementById("web-panel").innerHTML = '<iframe src="' + u + '"
width="100%" height="100%" border="0"></iframe>';}</script>

<select name="mydropdown" id="url" onchange="loadURL(this.value);">
<option value="http://123.com/opt.php?3">opt3</option>
<option value="http://123.com/opt.php?2">opt2</option>
<option value="http://123.com/opt.php?1">opt1</option>
</select>

<div id="web-panel"></div>
```

Comment: Are you taking about Ajax? You can find a basic example here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp and more information here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load content of an URL into a div without using the IFrame, you could try using jQuery Ajax approach: (the first line is important, as it includes the jQuery framework)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadURL(u) { 
    $.ajax({
        url: u,
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#web-panel").html(data);
    });
}
</script>

<select name="mydropdown" id="url" onchange="loadURL(this.value);">
<option value="http://123.com/opt.php?3">opt3</option>
<option value="http://123.com/opt.php?2">opt2</option>
<option value="http://123.com/opt.php?1">opt1</option>
</select>

<div id="web-panel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have JavaScript syntax error.

Change the JS part to look like this:

```
function loadURL(u) { 
    document.getElementById("web-panel").innerHTML = '<iframe src="' + u +
    '" width="100%" height="100%" border="0"></iframe>';
}
```